# How to configure Hibernate 5 with Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm, hibernate-5.x

I wanted to upgrade to Hibernate 5 but I can't get it to work for some weird reason.

My spring context configuration with Hibernate 4 looks like this:

```
....
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses" ref="hibernateClasses" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                ${hibernate.dialect}
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">
                ${hibernate.show_sql}
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">
                ${hibernate.generate_statistics}
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">
                ${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

....
```

I left out the datasource and the hibernateClasses beans definition.

For Hibernate 5 I changed the package name to hibernate5 like this:

```
....
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses" ref="hibernateClasses" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                ${hibernate.dialect}
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">
                ${hibernate.show_sql}
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">
                ${hibernate.generate_statistics}
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">
                ${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

....
```

when I run my tests the application context fails to start up because it cannot find the LocalSessionFactoryBean class :-S. This class resides in spring-orm JAR and is actually present but for some reason it cannot be found and throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder
```

My Maven dependencies are as follows:

```
    <!-- Servlet API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet-api.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring libraries -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>asm</groupId>
                <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>${cglib.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <version>${asm.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-mock</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-mock.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
        <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
        <version>${easymock.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>${hsqldb.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Does anybody have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is your hibernate-version in your pom file?

Comment: The version I use is 5.0.4.Final

Comment: whats your spring version ? I have the same problem with spring 4.2.6 and hibernate 5.5.3 configuration.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

May be you should add

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
  <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I had the same issue, and my initial logs complained about,

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException

Answer (score 8):

@sapna answer is working.

But for those curious about why it breaks between hibernate 5.0.3.Final and 5.0.4.Final, here is the answer : They removed the dependency on jta, which was :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
    <artifactId>geronimo-jta_1.1_spec</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

The change is described there : [HHH-10178](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10178)

So if you are upgrading from 5.0.x to 5.0.4 or 5.0.5 and wish to not change anything to your classpath, you should rather import this lib than the javax.transaction:jta one.

EDIT:
they reverted this change with hibernte 5.0.7 : [HHH-10307](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10307), so upgrading to this version or newer should also fix the issue.